# R - Split 1 Column Row of Multiple Values Into Data Frame

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, so please take it easy on me.

I'm killing myself trying to figure this out.

I have a giant block of text, which I've scraped from a website. It looks something like this (I've altered some of the information for privacy's sake):

```
> theText99 

499737 2016-03-31 10:37:29 00:00:32 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 
Person Name Completed\n499731 2016-03-31 10:36:50 00:13:50 SALES NON WORD 
INITIATIVE 160915 1234567891013 Woman Name Completed\n499726 2016-03-31 
10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES NON WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Someone Berry 
Completed\n499672 2016-03-31 10:29:13 00:00:09 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 
123456789101 Person Carr Completed\n499654 2016-03-31 10:27:16 00:00:09 SALES 
WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Person Carr Completed\n499609 2016-03-31 
10:18:36 00:11:06 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Person Carr 
Completed\n499601 2016-03-31 10:16:29 00:10:34 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 
123456789101 FirstName Kang Completed\n499568 2016-03-31 10:10:39 00:02:31 
SALES NON WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Person Carr Completed\n499548 
2016-03-31 10:06:40 00:07:15 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 1234567891011 Pat 
Laugh Completed\n499508 2016-03-31 09:56:34 00:02:51 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 
160915 123456789101 Mark LastName Completed\n499499 2016-03-31 09:54:33 
00:00:08 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Woman Name 
Completed\n499490 2016-03-31 09:53:04 00:04:28 SALES WORD INITIATIVE 160915 
123456789101 Person Name Completed
```

My goal is to parse this data into a data frame.

I've accomplished this much:

```
> library(stringr)
> t <- str_split(theText99, "\\n")
```

Which results in a nice set of lined text..

`[1] "499737 2016-03-31 10:37:29 00:00:32 SALES THING INITIATIVE 160915  123456789101 First Name Completed"

[2] "499731 2016-03-31 10:36:50 00:13:50 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Chelsea Hello Completed"

[3] "499726 2016-03-31 10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915      123456789101 Nice Name Completed"`

Put it into a data frame thinking I was getting somewhere:

```
> x <- as.data.frame(t)
> t <- x[1,] # To Test on the first row
> library(stringi)
> library(stringr)
> t <- as.character(t)
> callId <- str_extract(t, "^[0-9]{6}")
> callId
[1] "499737"
> callDate <- str_extract(t, "[0-9\\-]{10}")
> callDate
[1] "2016-03-31"
> callDuration <- str_extract(t, "[0-9\\:?]{8}")
> callDuration
[1] "10:37:29"
> callInitiative <- str_extract(t, "([A-Z]...+[A-Z]+...[0-9]+)")
> callInitiative
[1] "SALES BLAHBLAH INITIATIVE 160915"
> phoneNumber <- str_extract(t, "(\\d){7,}")
> phoneNumber
[1] 123456789101
> agentName <- str_extract(t, "([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+)")
> agentName
> FirstName LastName
```

Who knows if this code will hold up...The length of some variables changes every so often.

**My Question**
The last big of text, on each line, changes frequently:

For example:
[3] "499726 2016-03-31 10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915      123456789101 Nice Name **Completed**"

[3] "499726 2016-03-31 10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915      123456789101 Nice Name **Still Pending Decision**"

[3] "499726 2016-03-31 10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915      123456789101 Nice Name **Looking For Another Source of Stuff**"

**What is the best way to split all this info?**

I think I might be making too much work splitting strings...Is this a better way?

Most items will stay relatively the same length:

499726 - *6 Numbers*
2016-03-31 - *Same date format*
10:36:29 - *Same time format* 
00:07:57 - *Same time format* 
SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915 - *This changes, but it's all TEXT with a number at the end*
123456789101 - *Phone number, stays the same length* 
Nice Name - *Persons name. First Name, Last Name*
Completed - *This field changes. From 1 word to 5 words.*

Any advice would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm looking for the info to go into columns as such:

Example String:
499726 2016-03-31 10:36:29 00:07:57 SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915 123456789101 Nice Name Completed

Columns:

```
df <- data.frame(callID = 499726,
callDate = "2016-03-31",
callTime = "10:36:29",
callDuration = "00:07:57",
callInitiative = "SALES THINGY INITIATIVE 160915", 
phoneNumber = "123456789101",
agentName = "Nice Name",
callStatus = "Completed") 
## REemember, the data in this column could be anything from 'completed' to 
## Awaiting More Info' to 'Call Back Tomorrow' to 'Is Unaware of Anything 
## We're Saying' (etc)...From a string splitting perspective, this is 
## the last one that's giving me issues.`
```

Comment: what exactly are the columns that you are expecting in your dataframe by processing the text, can you please provide the sample output that you are expecting so that, I can try to help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the post now to give you an idea.

Comment: XML::readHTMLTable?
check out rvest package as well?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

x <- str_locate(t, agentName)
callStatus <- substr(t, (x[2]+2), nchar(t))